# Qt menubar shortcut doesn't work and no underline under option

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

There is implementation of simple main window:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QtWidgets>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QAction *someAction = new QAction(tr("&Action"), this);
    someAction->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Quit);
    connect(someAction, &QAction::triggered, this, &QWidget::close);

    QMenu* someMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&SomeMenu"));
    someMenu->addAction(someAction);
}
```

The menu option looks as following:

[image]

I would expect that there would be underline under leter `A` of word `Action` and that shortcut `Ctrl+Q` would quit program. However pressing `Ctrl+Q` does nothing and there is no underline. However when I click on this menu option by mouse then it works as expected. This was tested on Ubuntu with `Qt 5`. How to make the shortcut and underline work properly?

Comment: Do you have problems exactly with this simple example? If you have a more complex application, then do you have any event filters installed? Does it work if you launch your app with different styles (e.g. -style=widows)?

Comment: it didn't help - with this option window was rendered as normal Ubuntu window. And yes this is exactly this code + header + main, nothing special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is solved. I had previously installed Qt 5.2.1 by apt-get and this is Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed Qt 5.4.0 from official website, configured Qt Creator to use this one and using the same code everything started to work - shortcuts work and underline is under menu option.