# Shortcut of actions don’t display

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I simply add a shortcut to actions (on Ubuntu):

```
newaction->setShortcut(QKeysquence::New);
```

but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> doesn't display.

On windows it is ok.

How could I make this shortcut display on the menu?

Comment: @anoopknr Code formatting should only be used for actual code, not to keywords or names of technologies (so "Windows" shouldn't be formatted as code). See meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360491/4284627 and meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/349538. Please stop using code formatting incorrectly.

Comment: Not necessarily an exact duplicate, but take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555018/1485885). What Qt version are you using?